# ZonedDateTime with timezone added to print format

Tags: java, datetime, zoneddatetime, threetenbp

I'm using https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP in my project.

I have  org.threeten.bp

ZonedDateTime: 2019-07-25T**14:30:57+05:30**[Asia/Calcutta]

How can I get this printed with addition of the timezone hours? ie the result should have 2019-07-25T**20:00:57**

Comment: Your time is already with that addition offset. If you set offset `+00:00` you will get `2019-07-25T09:00:57+00:00`. Also you can look at Deadpool's answer to see how to done that. But in my opinion, that is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the offset in the form of seconds from `ZonedDateTime`

```
ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-07-25T14:30:57+05:30");
long seconds = time.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
```

Now get the `LocalDateTime` part from `ZonedDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime local = time.toLocalDateTime().plusSeconds(seconds);   //2019-07-25T20:00:57
```

**toLocalDateTime**

> Gets the LocalDateTime part of this date-time.

If you want to get the local date time in UTC use `toInstant()`

> This returns an Instant representing the same point on the time-line as this date-time. The calculation combines the local date-time and offset.

```
Instant i = time.toInstant();   //2019-07-25T09:00:57Z
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood. The offset of +05:30 in your string means that 5 hours 30 minutes *have already been added* to the time compared to UTC. So adding them once more will not make any sense.

If you want to compensate for the offset, simply convert your date-time to UTC. For example:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-07-25T14:30:57+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]");
    OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(utcDateTime);
```

Output:

> 2019-07-25T09:00:57Z